# Drawing line on canvas in the same position multiple times makes it more saturated

Tags: java, android

I have encountered a really weird drawing problem.
I want to create PDF and for that, I am using an android native PDF API that gives me a canvas to draw on.
After a while, I noticed that drawing line or rectangle several times in the same place is more saturated than a one that has been drawn once.
Here is my test code:

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0.5f);
        paint.setARGB(255,0,0,0);

        for(int i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
            canvas.drawLine(0, 10, PageRectangle.A4.getPointX(), 10, paint);

        canvas.drawLine(0, 20, PageRectangle.A4.getPointX(), 20, paint);
```

Here are the [results](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/289725877913124864/745619329424556042/6ee9f5dd148b20e7ad34777ab52acbfb.png)

Is there a way to remove this saturation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found out that `Canvas` provided by `PdfDocument.Page` does not draw in pixels, it draws in **PostScript Points**. This is the code that converts pixels to points:

```
/**
* Converting pixels to PostScript Points
* @param px pixels to convert
* @return PostScript Points
*/
public float convert(float px){
    return (px+0.5f) * 72f / 96;
}
```

Comment: With PDF I already expected _points_ as unit, but this is enlightening.

Comment: @JoopEggen Android documentation does not provide information on what kind of units canvas is drawing. As I have drawn custom views it always was pixels. It would be helpful for others if documentation stated on what kind of units `Canvas` is drawing.

Comment: Pixel is the hardware unit, the light element. The pixel resolution differs from writing to screen, writing to printer or writing to an other monitor (with different pts per pixel).

Answer (score 0):

That is due to scalable floating point geometry. A line will go through parts of pixels and thus there will be some transparency to such a pixel.

For half a pixel with a red line: 50% red, next time 75% red and so on.

Maybe you can reduce the effect by Graphics2D *hinting* (to shift to pixel borders), but it will never get completely lost. (`setStrokeWidth(0.5f)`)